# Почему появляется NullPointer in VideoView?

Tags: java, android, videoview

При запуске программа выдает NullPointer на строке `videoView.setVideoPath(videoSource);`
Подскажите, в чем может быть проблема? В манифесте все прописано, видео по ссылке существует.

```
public class PlayVideoActivity extends Activity {
VideoView videoView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_camera);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE); 
    String videoSource = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES).toString();
    Log.w("way",""+videoSource);
    videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView1);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String fName = intent.getStringExtra("source");
    videoSource = videoSource + "/1.3gp";
    videoView.setVideoPath(videoSource);
    videoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
    videoView.requestFocus(0);
    videoView.start();
}
```

}

xml - файл

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<VideoView
    android:id="@+id/videoView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Логи:

> 07-30 14:40:50.626: E/AndroidRuntime(17268): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   07-30 14:40:50.626: E/AndroidRuntime(17268):
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.example.video/com.example.video.PlayVideoActivity}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException 07-30 14:40:50.626:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(17268):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2070)
>   07-30 14:40:50.626: E/AndroidRuntime(17268):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2095)
>   07-30 14:40:50.626: E/AndroidRuntime(17268):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:135) 07-30
>   14:40:50.626: E/AndroidRuntime(17268):    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1201)
>   07-30 14:40:50.626: E/AndroidRuntime(17268):  at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 07-30
>   14:40:50.626: E/AndroidRuntime(17268):    at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 07-30 14:40:50.626:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(17268):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4849) 07-30
>   14:40:50.626: E/AndroidRuntime(17268):    at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 07-30
>   14:40:50.626: E/AndroidRuntime(17268):    at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 07-30 14:40:50.626:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(17268):  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:795)
>   07-30 14:40:50.626: E/AndroidRuntime(17268):  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:562) 07-30
>   14:40:50.626: E/AndroidRuntime(17268):    at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 07-30 14:40:50.626:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(17268): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>   07-30 14:40:50.626: E/AndroidRuntime(17268):  at
>   com.example.video.PlayVideoActivity.onCreate(PlayVideoActivity.java:26)
>   07-30 14:40:50.626: E/AndroidRuntime(17268):  at
>   android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5236) 07-30
>   14:40:50.626: E/AndroidRuntime(17268):    at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1082)
>   07-30 14:40:50.626: E/AndroidRuntime(17268):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2034)
>   07-30 14:40:50.626: E/AndroidRuntime(17268):  ... 11 more

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />

<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera.flash"
    android:required="true" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.front" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" >
</uses-permission>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".CameraActivityDirector"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".CameraActivityAssistant"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape" >
    </activity>
     <activity
        android:name=".PlayVideoActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape" >
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: Не могли бы Вы скинуть лог ошибки

Comment: @Mikhail Добавила.

Comment: AndroidManifest покажите

Comment: @АндройдАндройд Добавила.

Comment: videoSource у вас точно соответствует действительному пути видео файла?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`videoView` равен `null`, очевидно потому что элемента с id `videoView1` нет в `activity_camera.xml`.

Да, я видел что где-то у вас есть `videoView1` но не в `activity_camera.xml`, или у вас несколько `activity_camera.xml`.